# Apache refresh after anything but 200 Ok

Tags: apache, http, apache2

I have an Apache (2.2.20) and for a specific VirtualHost, I would like to make the Browser refresh the page when an error occurred.

the use-case is that I have many computers that just start a browser in full screen mode when they boot (think of them as display panels). The browser is directed to a page I dynamically render for each request. The page has a "Refresh 60" header so the browser reloads the page every minute. This works until an error occurrs while rendering the dynamic page, then the browser receives the 500 and stops the refreshing.

Apache's ErrorDocument directive doesn't help because it initiates a redirect after which refreshing the page doesn't direct back to the original page anymore.

I thought of doing

```
Header always set Refresh 5
Header onsuccess unset Refresh
```

in the VirtualHost configuration. Unfortunately, the above adds "Refresh 5" to every response.

How could I solve the Problem?

Comment: ErrorDocument only does a redirect if you give it a URL instead of a path to a file.  Can you show us the ErrorDocument directives you tried?

Comment: @Charles: I thought that I tried both and I swear they both redirected. I just tried again with a path and it does exactly what I want :/ Thanks a lot!